# Get product only with attributes used in product listing in a test

Tags: product, attributes, magento2.2.6, testing, product-listing

In my test I am creating a product like this:

```
$product = $this->objectManagerHelper->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$product
    ->setId(1)
    ->setTypeId(Product\Type::TYPE_SIMPLE)
    ->setWebsiteIds([1])
    ->setName('Simple Product 1')
    ->setSku('simple1')
    ->setPrice(10)
    ->setVisibility(Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
    ->setUrlKey('url-key2')
    ->setCategoryIds([2])
    ->setStockData([
        'use_config_manage_stock' => $manageStock,
        'qty' => $qty,
        'is_qty_decimal' => 0,
        'is_in_stock' => $isInStock
    ])
    ->setData('erp_procurement', $erpProcurement)
    ->setData('qty', $qty)
    ->setData('manage_stock', $manageStock)
    ->setData('stock_lead_time', $stockLeadTime)
    ->setData(Product::STATUS, $stockstatus)
    ->save();
```

But how can I have the product as if it is loaded in listing only with the attributes that have `used_in_product_listing` set to `true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/1155) I found the method `getAttributesUsedInListing()` in `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Config`. The idea from Alex was a good hint.

1. Creating a collection
2. Filtering by the product id
3. Adding attributes
   from `getAttributesUsedInListing()` to the select

solved the problem.

Here my code:

```
$productCollection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
$productCollection->addIdFilter($product->getId());
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect($this->getAttributesUsedInListing());
$product = $productCollection->getFirstItem();

private function getAttributesUsedInListing()
{
    $attributeCodes = [];
    $attributes = $this->config->getAttributesUsedInListing();

    array_walk_recursive($attributes, function ($value, $key) use (&$attributeCodes) {
        if ($key == 'attribute_code') {
            $attributeCodes[] = $value;
        }
    });
    return $attributeCodes;
}
```

I used `$this->getAttributesUsedInListing()` to create an array with only the attribute codes in the array to pass it to `addAttributeToSelect()`.

Answer (score 0):

This should also work

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config */
protected $config;

...

$attributes = array_keys($this->config->getAttributesUsedInProductListing());
```